# MaskTextInputFormatter erases characters when I do the insertion

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I am using [MaskInputFormatter](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter/example) to format a phone number textfield and it's a customTextField I created. When I insert the number it erases the previous digit. And when a non-number character is inserted it erases all the inserted data.

[image: ScreenRecording]

I tried using it in a 'vanilla' TextFormField and had the same result.

```
TextFormField(
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      mobile.setContactNumber(value);
    });
  },
  initialValue:
      mobile.contactNumber,
  inputFormatters: [MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: "+258 ###-##-##")],
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final  maskFormatter = MaskTextInputFormatter( mask: '+### ###-##-##');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
       child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50,),
          TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Phone Number'
              ),
              inputFormatters: [
                maskFormatter
              ],
          ),
        ],
       ),
     ), 
    );
  }
}
```

[image: That's how it works for me.]

Comment: Thanks. It worked to declare the formatter outside.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```html
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final  maskFormatter = MaskTextInputFormatter( mask: '+### ###-##-##');
  _controller=TextEditingController(text: "+258 ");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
       child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50,),
          TextField(
          controller:_controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Phone Number'
              ),
              inputFormatters: [
                maskFormatter
              ],
          ),
        ],
       ),
     ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**